# How to get the Envelope content in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: javascript, wso2

This is my Envelope Payload in System Logs:

```
Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><schema><Id>A49E-D293-CB27-AA31</Id><name>John</name></schema></jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

If I want to get the "Id" content, how can I do in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case the solution is

```
<property name="Id" expression="json-eval($.schema.Id)"/>
```

If you really want to use javascript this should work

```
<script description="Get ID" language="js"><![CDATA[
var json = mc.getPayloadJSON();
var Id = json.schema.Id;
]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read it like this. (change below as per your json request)

```
 <log>
     <property name="location" expression="json-eval($.coordinates.location[0].name)"></property>
 </log>
```

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/JSON+Support